# How can custom compilation parameters be synchronized through the Android studio project?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

Some parameters in my project need to be passed in at compile time.

So there is such a fragment in my `build.gradle` file:

```
assemble {
    description 'Check the necessary parameters and terminate compilation if they do not exist.'
    if (!project.hasProperty('customArgs')) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Parameter customArgs is not defined")
    }
}
```

When I compile, I will use the command `gradle build -PcustomArgs=1234`

Everything was fine until I imported the project into Android studio.

Gradle project sync is always fails.

[image]

That is to say, in the process of project synchronization, I can't find any place where I can set parameters.

In other words, how to set the parameters of sync in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this custom behavior from the configuration phase to the execution phase. Otherwise Android Studio will execute it when configuring you project.

```
assemble {
    doLast {
        description 'Check the necessary parameters and terminate compilation if they do not exist.'
        if (!project.hasProperty('customArgs')) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Parameter customArgs is not defined")
        }
    }
}
```

More informations [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)